# Backbone.js force to login route

Tags: backbone.js, routes

I'm developing an application where my user needs to login, in this sense logging in is slightly different as the user isn't registered per say. They enter their name, and room name then they connect. The room itself contains all of the settings required for the users such as;

- Room name
- View settings - allowing options to be on or off
- etc...

So what I'm looking to do is hook on to the route event, so I can force the user to go to the `/login` root if they're not logged in.

Surely there must be a DRY way of doing this without adding a conditional to each route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option that comes to my mind is to overwrite the current `Router.route` -function, currently it looks like [this](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-124):

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
  if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
  if (!callback) callback = this[name]; // this is of interest
  Backbone.history.route(route, _.bind(function(fragment) {
    var args = this._extractParameters(route, fragment);
    callback && callback.apply(this, args);
    this.trigger.apply(this, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
    Backbone.history.trigger('route', this, name, args);
  }, this));
  return this;
},
```

What you want to do is to wrap each and every callback with a function that checks if the condition you want is met and then either calls the wrappee or reroutes to login. Underscore's [`wrap` -function](http://underscorejs.org/#wrap) is useful here.

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
  ... // same as above
  if (!callback) callback = this[name];
  _.wrap(callback, function(cb) {
    if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
      cb();
    } else {
      this.navigate("url/to/login");
    }
  });
  ... // same as above
},
```

of course you have to add a check for the actual login route so that you don't create an infinite loop!

**EDIT:**

You don't have to modify the source, the most simple way to do this is:

```
var CustomRouter = Router.extend({
  route: function() {
    // your overwrite here
  }
});
```

Use this over the one in the comments as it is native to Backbone!

Hope this helps

Comment: I guess this means modifying the core Backbone.js file right? There isn't a way of doing this without?

Comment: @James, you don't need to modify the Backbone source, you can override it: `Backbone.Router.prototype.route = function(route, name, callback) { ... }`.

Comment: modified my answer, I would prefer the Backbone `extend` over fiddling with `prototype`

Comment: Minor change: you need to save the callback back into the callback variable, otherwise it won't run your new code. Eg: `callback=_.wrap...`

Answer (score 4):

[Backbone's Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) has an `execute` method that you can override. It is called every time a route is matched, before the callback is called:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  execute: function(callback, args) {
    // Do what you want here! 
    if (callback) callback.apply(this, args);
  }
});
```

The method was added with the 1.1.1 release on Feb. 13, 2014.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand on @jakee answer and @Joel Nation comment. I had troubles making `this` work in the affected routes as expected. I was getting "this is undefined". Below the final code that made it work:

```
  Backbone.Router.prototype.route = function(route, name, callback) {
    if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
    if (_.isFunction(name)) {
      callback = name;
      name = '';
    }
    if (!callback) callback = this[name];
    // here my custom code
    callback = _.wrap(callback, _.bind(function(cb) {
      if (name == 'login' || sessionModel.authenticated()) {
        _.bind(cb, this)();
      } else {
        this.navigate('login', {trigger: true});
      }
    }, this));
    // finish my custom code
    var router = this;
    Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
      var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);
      callback && callback.apply(router, args);
      router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
      router.trigger('route', name, args);
      Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
    });
    return this;
  };
```

Notice `_.wrap` and `_.bind` so `this` is the one that you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

In your code that initializes the application:

```
// Initialize router(s)
Backbone.history.on("route", function() {
    if (!authenticated) Backbone.history.navigate("/login", true);
});
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: What bonus would doing it this way have to overwriting the events as suggested by @jakee?

Comment: This doesn't execute before the route is routed I'm afraid.

Comment: Seems you're right. This will execute after the route is triggered. In that case, I'd suggest using @jakee's suggestion, making sure that inside your custom `route()` function, after you check if authenticated and route to login if necessary, you make a call to `Backbone.Router.prototype.route.apply(this, arguments);`